# How to define a ng-model dynamically when using $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wan't to use $index in order  to create a new $scope variable:

```
    <div ng-repeat="i in items track by $index">   
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" 
             ng-model="myVariableName{{$index}}" >
            ....
```

I wan't to declare the variable: myVariableName0, myVariableName1, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In the controller declare empty object

```
$scope.myVariableName = {};
```

And in the template assign the model value as a property of an object.

```
ng-model="myVariableName[$index]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this you can have an array, and each item of that array can refer to the current `ng-model` via `ng-model="myVariableName[$index]"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
```

```css
input,
span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <input type='text' ng-repeat='temp in [0,1,2,3]' ng-model='$parent["myVariableName" + $index]' />
  <span>0: {{myVariableName0}}</span>
  <span>1: {{myVariableName1}}</span>
  <span>2: {{myVariableName2}}</span>
  <span>3: {{myVariableName3}}</span>
</div>
```